For std::vector<std::any>, why GCC has different results from MSVC
GCC:
myVector size is 1
myVector2 size is 2
MSVC:
myVector size is 3
myVector2 size is 2
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::any> myVector = {
        std::vector<std::any>{1, 2, 3}
    };
    std::cout << myVector.size() << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::any> myVector2 = {
        std::vector<std::any>{1, 2, 3},
        std::vector<std::any>{1, 2, 3}
    };
    std::cout << myVector2.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The results given by MSVC seem counter-intuitive,when I try push_back std::vector<std::any>{1, 2, 3} to myVector,in MSVC,the size of myVector is 1.But I don't want to use this method. How can I make MSVC give intuitive results, that is the size of myVector is 1

for example:
std::vectorstd::any myVector = { std::vectorstd::any{1, 2, 3} };
I need to make sure that the data type in myVector is std::vectorstd::any and not three integers 1,2,3

How do you compile? What compiler versions do you use? Are you aware of the distinct default C++ versions set in various compilers?

platform：windows
GCC：11.2.0
MSVC： Visual Studio 2022-17.9.5
C++ standard：c++17
